# Design considerations for interactive shapes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Grid` with an arbitrary number (possibly thousands) of filled [shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) with states (mouse hovered, selected, dragging...). If several objects overlap, hovering/clicking them should select the one with its center point closest to the mouse position.

Considering both performance and code design, what is the best way to solve this?

### Some questions

1. Should I create the shapes in code behind and add them to some grid's children or should I have some clever XAML binding to a list of some objects (a tutorial would be nice)?
2. I want to handle mouse events. Should each shape have its own mouse handlers or should I have *one* mouse handler for the parent grid where I look for the nearest shape?
3. Shape styles should be editable by the user. Should I define them as resources or properties in code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. Why do you use a Grid? Looks like a [Canvas](http://wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html) would fit better your needs.
2. Use routed events. Just handle the event of the container (mouse xxx, and then find out where the mouse is located and what is the shape that must receive the action).
3. You must define a generic shape control with a public Style property where the end user can declare his own style.